# When would I acquire a lock with block state set to False?

Tags: python, locking, multiprocessing

I was wondering why ever setting `block=false` would make sense?

```
 from multiprocessing import Process, Lock
 lock.acquire(block=False)
```

If i don't need to block, I wouldn't use Lock at all?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From `Python in a Nutshell`:

> L.acquire()
>   When 
>   blocking
>    is True, acquire locks 
>   L
>   . If 
>   L
>    is already locked, the calling thread suspends and waits until 
>   L
>    is unlocked,
>   then locks 
>   L
>   . Even if the calling thread was the one that last locked 
>   L
>   , it still suspends and waits until another thread
>   releases 
>   L
>   . When 
>   blocking
>    is False and 
>   L
>    is unlocked, acquire locks 
>   L
>    and returns True. When 
>   blocking
>    is False and 
>   L
>    is
>   locked, acquire does not affect 
>   L
>   , and returns False.

And a practical example using the following simple code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock, current_process


def blocking_testing(lock):
    if not lock.acquire(False):
        print('{} Couldn\'t get lock'.format(current_process().ident))
    else:
        print('{} Got lock'.format(current_process().ident))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    lock = Lock()
    for i in range(3):
        procs = []
        p = Process(target=blocking_testing, args=(lock,))
        procs.append(p)
        p.start()
        for p in procs:
            p.join()
```

With the above version (`blocking=False`) this outputs

> 12206 Got lock
>   12207 Couldn't get lock
>   12208 Couldn't get lock

If I set `blocking=True` (or remove it, as it defaults to `True`) the main process will hang, as the `Lock` is not being released.
Finally, if I set `blocking=True` and add a `lock.release()` at the end, my output will be

> 12616 Got lock
>   12617 Got lock
>   12618 Got lock

I hope this was a clear enough explanation.

Answer (score 3):

`multiprocessing.Lock` is not used for blocking, it's used to protect one or more resources from concurrent access.

The simplest of the examples could be a file written by multiple processes. To guarantee that only one process at a time is writing on the given file, you protect it with a `Lock`.

There are situations where your logic cannot block. For example, if your logic is orchestrated by an event loop like the `asyncio` module, blocking would stop the entire execution until the `Lock` is released.

In such cases the common approach is trying to acquire the `Lock`. If you succeed, you proceed accessing the protected resource, otherwise you move to other routines and try later.

Answer (score 2):

This is make sense as its parameter's name: `block`. `block=False` provide a non-blocking function to access protected resources.

Example one:

You have a GUI thread and a background work thread. Your GUI thread needs to modify some data generated by work thread, but your GUI thread cannot block as it will block the whole interaction. So you can use `lock.acquire(block=False)` to safely check if data is ready without blocking.

Example two:

Another example related to event loop is `asyncio`, this provide a non-blocking access to protected resources.